# Quando usar sublinhado em hyperlinks web?

Tags: aplicação-web, link, ux

Quando eu comecei na web todos *hyperlinks* eram sublinhados. Depois isso deixou de ser usado, praticamente não se usa mais em lugar algum. Existe um motivo para não usar mais? Ainda tem alguma situação para usar? Deveria usar um sublinhado com visual diferente (pontilhado, tracejado, etc.)?

Por outro lado praticamente ninguém usa o sublinhado para destacar texto, existia um bom motivo que era não confundir com *link*, mas se o sublinhado não é usado pra isso, porque não usar?

Preciso de um justificativa plausível e não apenas uma opinião, se possível alguma referência que confirme.

Comment: Acredito que essa seja uma situação muito ligada ao Design e/ou UI/UX. Ou seja, cabe entender o conceito do que você está construindo. Como o sublinhado era padrão e foi muito difundido, acabou ficando muito comum (como a boa e velha comic sans) por isso caiu em desuso. Quanto as estilizações do sublinhado, pontilhado por exemplo, esse estilo tem que estar em conformidade com os demais elementos do site/aplicativo. Acho que o conceito de sublinhado ainda é muito amarrado aos hiperlinks, por isso que é tão difícil ver ele em outras situações. Resumo, você não é impedido de usar, o sublinhado in

Comment: Com essa tendência minimalista que hoje existe no mercado de UX e como a maioria das pessoas aprenderam, ao longo do tempo, a identificar e entender o que é um link, isso deve ter motivado a esse desuso. Mas um padrão de link que vejo é que sempre o link está na cor azul como o próprio site do Stack Overflow. O uso do sublinhado pode ficar mais associado a textos muito longos, a Wikipédia deixa o sublinhado apenas quando o usuário passa o mouse no link, destacando com a cor azul.

Comment: O hiperlink sublinhado tornou-se um dos recursos mais comuns e mais reconhecíveis da nossa experiência on-line. Os links são fáceis de encontrar porque os usuários entendem que o texto sublinhado significa que é um link. O sublinhado chama a atenção deles. Quando você remove os encargos para os usuários, você evita atrasos e oferece acesso rápido ao conteúdo desejado. Texto sublinhado azul é apenas uma das muitas maneiras de indicar que um link é um link (mas porque tem sido a convenção por tanto tempo, você realmente não deve usar texto sublinhado azul para não-links).

Comment: Eu não posso afirmar nada, mas gostaria de opinar, creio que provavelmente seja por "gosto", os links sublinhados lembram sites mais antigos, o que não costuma agradar os desenvolvedores ou até o usuário final, talvez por parecer estranho no meio de tantos "efeitos novos", ainda sim noto em artigos e algumas páginas. Pergunta muito interessante, vou acompanhar no favoritos (bem que o favoritos poderia nos notificar de novas respostas e edições :/)

Comment: Por isso mesmo não respondi, pois era apenas opinião, ainda sim não sei se encontrará algo que não caia em opinião apenas, por melhor que a resposta pareça.

Comment: https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/7064

Answer (score 6):

O padrão sempre foi links azuis e sublinhados, é isso que os usuários esperam. Porém com a evolução no design das páginas foi-se acostumando a personalizar os links. Nada te impede de mudar o visual dos links, mas pesquisas indicam que, quanto mais próximos do padrão, maior é a taxa de conversão, veja no link abaixo:

[Usability Split Test Results: Link Appearance Matters More Than You Think…](http://www.conversiondoctor.com/conversion-blog/usability-split-test-results-link-appearance-matters-more-than-you-think)

Mas já que o padrão não é tão agradável visualmente, a recomendação é: "Links textuais deveriam ser coloridos e sublinhados", aqui tem um bom guia sobre esse assunto:
[Guidelines for Visualizing Links](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/guidelines-for-visualizing-links/)

espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 2):

Bom voltando um pouco na história, podemos perceber que a utilização dos links no formato mais conhecido foi em razão de alguns fatores principais. E no inicio da década de 90 a sua utilização era muita necessária devido aos poucos recursos disponíveis na época.

Uma fala bem conhecida de Tim Berners-Lee ( criador da WWW ) foi:

> "A WWW (World Wide Web) consiste de documentos e links." 1991

**- Como surgiu o texto Azul e sublinhado?**

Devido a essa importância se fazia necessária um diferenciação do restante do texto para que o link fosse mais facilmente reconhecido.
Desde sempre a utilização de textos sublinhados era tida como uma má prática ([Sublinhado..Absolutamente não!](https://practicaltypography.com/underlining.html)), e por isso quase nenhum texto possuía essa característica. Por isso a utilização de sublinhado foi escolhida para representar um link.

- Tá entendi o porque do sublinhado mas, e o **azul**?

De acordo com algumas fontes ([Link](http://www.uxbooth.com/articles/is-the-underlined-link-hurting-readability/),[Link2](https://usabilitygeek.com/hyperlink-usability-guidelines-usable-links/)), isso foi um acidente da história: no tempo em que estava sendo criado o protótipo da WWW, a maioria dos computadores possuíam uma limitação que era o total de cores disponíveis no display (Na época 16). E o **azul** era a segunda cor mais escura fora o preto. Por isso a escolha e definição do link como vemos a tanto tempo .

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Link Azul e Sublinhado*

**- Por que houve a migração na formatação dos Links?**

Isso iniciou devido a uma decisão da Google em 2014, que decidiu remover essa formatação antiga nos resultados do seu buscador ([Google remove sublinhado de links](https://www.theverge.com/2014/3/13/5503894/google-removes-underlined-links-site-redesign)). Decisão essa tomada principalmente pelo na época diretor de designer Jon Wiley, que segundo ele:

> "Melhorar a forma de leitura e criar no geral um ambiente mais limpo"

Alguns outros vários sites na época seguindo a mesma vertente seguiram o mesmo padrão e mudaram a formação de seus links.

O site NNgroup que é focado em experiência do usuário publicou na época um trecho sobre links que diz:

> "A posição dos links pode ajudá-lo a determinar se é necessário sublinhar ou não. O menu de navegação e as listas, especialmente ao longo das áreas periféricas da página, não exigem sublinhado. Suas localizações os identificam como links."

Texto na íntegra: [Beyond Blue Links: Making Clickable Elements Recognizable](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/clickable-elements/)

**- Então por que essa formatação (Sublinhada) permanece até hoje em alguns locais?**

Apesar de novas tecnologias, novas ideias de design e possibilidades terem surgido, a formatação do link se manteve a mesma em alguns locais pois, ajuda os iniciantes na tecnologia a um rápido entendimento do que podem acessar e oque já visitaram (*Link azul escuro*), ajuda a usuários em geral a se concentrar em pontos importantes da página que podem levar a outros locais. De acordo com o Designer de produtos e Desenvolvedor Lee Munroe,  o usuário não lê, muitas vezes ele simplesmente escaneia ([Guia definitivo para links Web](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/02/the-definitive-guide-to-styling-web-links/)). 
Além disso, pessoas com discromatismo(Enxergam somente branco e preto) e daltonismo(Enxergam cores trocadas), não tem dificuldade de encontrar um sublinhado. Algo que não ocorre com Links que possuem somente COR diferenciada.
E complementando alguns profissionais de design ainda entendem que a formatação antiga ainda é a ideal na relação ***design x praticidade***

- **Outras fontes consultadas**
- [Comparing Link Marker Visualization Techniques –
  Changes in Reading Behavior](https://vsis-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/getDoc.php/publications/119/www2003.pdf)
- [Less Is Still More: The Importance Of The Minimalist Approach To Web Design](https://usabilitygeek.com/less-is-more-importance-minimalist-web-design/)
- [Google's Marissa Mayer believes real-time searching could change the way we navigate the internet](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2009/jul/08/google-search-marissa-mayer)
- [THE WEBBY AWARDS GALLERY + ARCHIVE](http://webbyawards.com/winners/2015/websites/website-features-and-design/best-visual-design-aesthetic/)
- [Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG) Overview](https://www.w3.org/WAI/standards-guidelines/wcag/)
- [How to Find Existing Vocabularies](https://www.w3.org/TR/ld-bp/)

Enfim, como opinião pessoal acredito que o decaimento da utilização de *links* sublinhados ocorreu devido as novas tendencias que as empresas/ pessoas buscam para todas as áreas, e os *links*, por já manterem o mesmo formato a tanto tempo tendem a cair na mira dessas novas tendências de padrões de design. Ao meu ver realmente a retirada desse padrão antigo ajuda na visualização (quando a página possui muitos links).